# Duplicating authentication data between the store and localStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In many React tutorials I have seen the presence of tokens or some other kind of data in localStorage used to drive authentication state in an app. But if I were to make a header/navbar component that shows a link to "sign in" or "sign out" as appropriate for the user's authentication, it appears that I would have to duplicate that localStorage token as state either in a redux store or in a component in order to prompt a re-render when authentication state changes.  Perhaps this bothers me more than it should, but duplicating that information seems redundant and also might necessitate some kind of dummy action to properly set authentication state if there is a pre-existing token in localStorage when a user first visits the app or refreshes the page.

Is there a better way to handle authentication data in a React app than what I have described here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to take a look into the library [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). It handles all the saving and restoring of your redux state for you between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't keep auth tokens/data in Redux or local state, I use an auth module that just reads/writes `localStorage`, and conditionally render the navbar:

```
<div>
   ...
   <a>{Auth.isAuthenticated() ? 'Sign Out' : 'Sign In'}</a>
</div>
```

and `Auth.js`:

```
class Auth {
    static storeToken(token) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    }

    static isAuthenticated() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null
    }

    static removeToken() {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
    }

    static getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
}

export default Auth
```

This still isn't ideal imo since all my state is not in one place, but I do think it is a little better than duplicating information like you said

Comment: What I'm using currently is exactly like what you have here, but the big issue is that without a change in props or state, the component will not re-render.  i.e., I'll sign in, but that navbar/header component will not update accordingly.